# Receiving Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I made a function to get an edge from a list:

Here is my code:

```
public EdgeNode getEdge(int ind)
{
    EdgeNode t = edges.start;
    for (int i = 0; i < ind; i++)
    {
        t = t.next;
        if (t.next == null)
            break;
    }
        return t;

}
```

I am receiving a null pointer error and it points to that function and I have no idea what is going wrong. It keeps crashing, can someone please help me?

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at MST.findMST(MST.java:45)
at Test.main(Test.java:21)
```

Edgenode:

```
public class EdgeNode
{
    int u;
    int v;
    int weight;
    EdgeNode next;

//  If the edges weights are the same then compare the
//  edge names lexicographically.

    public boolean lessThan(EdgeNode edge)
    {
        if (weight < edge.weight)
            return true;
        else if (weight == edge.weight)
        {
            if (u < edge.u)
                return true;
            else if (u > edge.u)
                return false;
            else if (u == edge.u)
                if (v < edge.v)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
        }
        else if (weight < edge.weight) {
            return false;
}
        return false;
    }

    public EdgeNode(int x, int y, int w)
    {
        u= x; 
        v= y; 
        weight=w;
        next= null;
    }
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.format("(%3d, %3d):%3d  ", u, v, weight);
    }
}
```

Line 44/45:

```
EdgeNode temp = G.getEdge(k);
int u = temp.u;
```

Here:

```
C:\Users\John\Desktop\updated>javac Test.java

C:\Users\John\Desktop\updated>java Test < one.txt
The edges in the graph:
(  0,   1):  1  (  0,   2):  3  (  0,   3):  1  (  1,   2):  2  (  1,   3):  1

(  2,   3):  2
4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at MST.findMST(MST.java:45)
        at Test.main(Test.java:21)
```

Comment: You probably haven't initialized something. Show us `egdes.start` is and `t.next` comes from. You ay also want to show your code for `EdgeNode` class.

Comment: You haven't shown us enough of your code for anybody to help.  At the very least we need to see the entire declaration of `EdgeNode` plus `findMST` and the main method.

Comment: Also add the complete stack trace (via copy/paste, don't retype it).

Comment: Have you tried running this in a IDE debugger to see what's null at the exception point?  Do that now before you do anything else.  You can probably answer your own question if you'll take the time to debug it properly.

Comment: Can anyone assist me?

Comment: could you show us EdgeNode's source code ?

Comment: Can u show the entire stack trace? and point out as per your code what is at line 45 in findMST().

Answer (score 0):

If u have no nodes then t.next in the 1st line itself will cause a `NullPointerException`.
Hence, first you need to check if there is a node and then see if there is a next node. I.e. Edges.start() might not return you any value. and hence first check if `t!=null` and then fetch `t.next()`

Comment: Without seeing more code this is at best a guess.  The exception is in `findEdges()`, not `getEdge()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that t is some list of something. If any one of the items in list t is null, as soon as it is discovered, the program immediately exits the loop and returns that null pointer. Hence the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

```
EdgeNode t = edges.start;
```

Maybe edges is not initialized properly, and gets a null value.

Answer (score -1):

If " t = t.next;" is null, you are still using "t.next== null" which is causing null pointer exception